# Jquery plugin or HTML canvas plugin for CIE charts

Tags: jquery

I'm getting crazy.
I need to embed in my website some monitor and TV measurement and I need to generate runtime some CIE and gamut charts.

I found chart.js, but I cannot found any plugin to generate this type of chart.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

### Chromaticity Diagrams

I've not heard of any JS chart frameworks that can handle Chromaticity Diagrams. Wolfram have an embeddable 'player' here: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CIEChromaticityDiagram/. You will probably have to create your own.

1. Use a CIE image as the background plot area for a canvas element. (Wikipedia has a good CIE image).
2. Use JQuery to plot points over the image based on your calculations.

Examples of canvas elements at work can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/).

There are many other charting frameworks for Javascript. See a comparison here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_charting_frameworks

### Getting started with chart.js

chart.js can be used to create charts on your website. Do the following to get started:

1. Download chart.js
2. Work through the chart.js documentation here - http://www.chartjs.org/docs/
3. Identify your data source. This could be a database, file or inline source.
4. Get the data via an ajax call. (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp)

The data object looks something like this:

```
var data = {
labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(225,0,0,1)",
    data: [12, 16, 13, 15, 18, 21] // 6 data points relating to the months above
    },
    {
    fillColor: "rgba(0,26,225,1)",
    data: [18, 16, 17, 17, 18, 16]
    }
]}
```

You can tweak many chart options using the options variable:

```
var options = { 
    scaleOverlay: true,
    scaleShowGridLines: true,
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: 4,
    scaleStepWidth: 5,
    scaleStartValue: 0,
    scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
    // ...
};
```

To instantiate a new chart, use:

```
var TheChartElement = document.getElementById('AChart').getContext("2d");
var NewBarChart = new Chart(TheChartElement).Bar(data, options);
```

Comment: I know, but I need CIE charts. Like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Cie_Chart_with_sRGB_gamut_by_spigget.png)